# .net Core service taking too long to start up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a .net core service. At first, I tried to start it as-is, with all my services being injected. I publish the app as self contained, but when I tried to add this as a service via cmd line, and start it, I received an error :

> Windows could not start the XXX service on Local Computer.
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

This would occur about 10 seconds after I click start, and the progress bar runs about halfway (at a medium speed).

Fair enough, maybe all my services are taking too long to start up, so I cleared them out from the ConfigureServices section, as a test run.

Now, after I've added the service when I try to start it up. Same as before, the progress bar starts running at a medium speed, but now it gets past the halfway-mark, then it starts to move slowly. When it reaches the end, I still get the previous message, but the Status of the service (in the Service Manager window) is now stuck on starting.

My Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            );
}
```

My Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm not doing anything that would keep the service from starting up, yet something is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried following the troubleshooting steps mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @FrancoisduPlessis, I have not. Doing so now.

Comment: @FrancoisduPlessis, I owe you a beer. First thing I noted while skimming over, was the I dont have .UseWindowsService() specified. After following that section, it's starting up. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad you got it running! You found the answer so you can post the answer yourself :) I just pointed you to some documentation :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My hostbuilder didnt specify .UseWindowsService(), like this :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            );
```

In order to use that, I had to add a reference to  Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

This  [troubleshooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)  led me to my answer.